# Blood pressure measurement

Tags: blood-pressure

When measuring your blood pressure in your arm, when you hear the sound to measure the systolic, is that sound NOT the heartbeat?

Comment: what do you define by "heart beat"? The *sound* of the heart beating or the *rate* of the heart beating?

Answer (score 3):

The sound in question is called the [Korotkoff sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korotkoff_sounds):

> If the pressure is dropped to a level equal to that of the patient's
>   systolic blood pressure, the first Korotkoff sound will be heard. As
>   the pressure in the cuff is the same as the pressure produced by the
>   heart, some blood will be able to pass through the upper arm when the
>   pressure in the artery rises during systole. This blood flows in
>   spurts as the pressure in the artery rises above the pressure in the
>   cuff and then drops back down beyond the cuffed region, resulting in
>   turbulence that produces an audible sound.

Comment: I'm glad you found that info. I wasn't sure if the question was asking about the sound of the heart or some artificial sound cuffs make.

Comment: @mattkaeo blood pressure + measurement = Korotkoff sounds, this what the question is about...